# what does the region attribute inside cache element in a Hibernate hbm xml do?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I am really stuck here and could not find the appropriate information on the entire web.

What does the `region` attribute inside `<cache />` element in a Hibernate hbm xml do?

I am expecting a verbose explanation in the answer apart form the official [jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html?#d0e2685) about cache element in a Hibernate hbm xml in.

Asking more specifically, when setting `setCacheble(true)` on the queries/criteria; **which cache region is selected by default**; the **StandardQueryCache** region or the one specified in the **entity hbm.xml file**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"region" attribute in cache element in a Hibernate hbm xml is used to give the name of your cache. When ever you use setCacheble(true) then a query is inserted or searched only in this cache region.

Region name is used a lot of places for example to delete all cache from a particular Region, to check hit count, miss count etc.

example to clear cache:

```
sessionFactory.evictQueries("cacheReginName");
```

We can have multiple cache region over a table.

```
Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(tableName.class);
                cri.setCacheRegion("cacheReginName");
```

or

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("select name from tableName where Id=1");
qry.setCacheRegion("cacheReginName");
```

When ever we use above code than only given cache region is searched or if query not found then a new query is inserted in this region.

If no cache region is set while fetching the data then cache region mentioned in hbm.xml is used.

If no cache region is mentioned in hbm.xml then default cache region name is  your class tags name attribute.

Using the multiple cache region can be according to your requirement.